# How do you scope Javascript that uses prototypes, so it can be called from a function and avoid global variables calls

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, prototype-programming

I've utilized Javascript's prototype to create an easily accessible method, but I am having trouble putting together a proper class that can be used for calling those methods.

Anyone have an idea on how I would instantiate an object through the use of a prototype method?

---

### Code that needs to be scoped

```
    var property = function () {};

    property.prototype.get = function () {
        return this.value;
    };

    property.prototype.set = function (value_) {
        this.value = value_;
    };
 ////////////////////////////////

    var id = function (id) {
        property.call(this);
        this.value = id;
    };
    id.prototype = Object.create(property.prototype);
    id.prototype.constructor = id;

 ////////////////////////////////

 var b = new id(5);
 var d = new id('A');

 ////////////////////////////////

 b.get(); //5
 d.get(); //A
 b.set('a'); //a
 d.set('b'); //b
 b.get(); //a
 d.get(); //b
```

---

### Desired - Inserting operational code into a class

```
var property = function(data) {

    property.prototype.get = function () {
         console.log(this.value);
         return this.value;
     };
     property.prototype.set = function (value_) {
         this.value = value_;
     };
     return{
        id: function() {
            //code here
        },
        foo: function() {
            //code here
        },
        data: function() {
            //code here
        },
```

---

### One of many on going failed attempts.

```
var property = function () {
    return {
        id: function (id) {
            VenueContentRow.call(this);
            this.value = id;
            this.prototype = Object.create(property.prototype);
            this.prototype.constructor = this;
        }
    }
};
property.prototype.get = function () {
    console.log(this.value);
    return this.value;
};
property.prototype.set = function (value_) {
    this.value = value_;
};

////////////////////////////////
var test = new property();
var d = new test.id('A');
////////////////////////////////

d.get();
d.set('b');
d.get();
```

---

p.s. - Sorry if my terminology causes confusion.

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: Describe the error/wrong output you are getting. Do you want `id` to extend `property` ?

Comment: @JuanMendes - Apologies for the formatting on the initial post.

_I am trying to figure out how to use `id` to `extend property` as I did in the operational code above._

I am trying to figure out how to do that via a class and method as described in the idealized code.

Comment: @Amit apologies for the format. I hope I have clarified what I am trying to do after revising my question.

Comment: Why do you want to set the prototype in the constructor? That's really problematic.

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish is very unclear, and so is the problem (or downside) in your working code.

Comment: @MikeC after modularizing your code, you can import the javascript and easily assign a method to a new object. i.e. `var i = new id; i.get() //value return;`

Comment: @JosephMCasey Sure but none of that requires setting up the prototype in the constructor. There's no reason to ever do that.

Comment: @Amit I'll try to further clarify the problem by pointing out an emphasis? **Question:** How to **scope** **prototype** **method** into **class**?

Comment: @JosephMCasey **Bold** letters **don't** help. You still haven't posted running code, actual output and expected output. Also, remember that there are no classes in JavaScript

Comment: @JuanMendes Both the operational code has the output and expected output listed. My problem is scoping the methods to into a javascript class.

Comment: @MikeC The only way to properly pass methods around in functional programming in JS is by using prototype, so I am using it for that reason. Otherwise it becomes a big mess of spaghetti code.

Comment: @JosephMCasey A: That's not true. B: I'm not suggesting avoiding using the prototype chain altogether. What I'm saying is you shouldn't define the prototype inside of the constructor of a class. Check my answer and see if that helps.

Comment: Putting constructors on instances (`new (new property()).id('A');`) is a bad idea. I don't think that's really what you want. Can you please show us how you'd ideally like to use your classes, and what results they would give in that example?

Comment: @Bergi the operational code is what I would like to implement since it works, but I would like to add the operational code, which is really a method, to a class to prevent issues with scoping. _Usually I do not have issues with calling the methods from a class, so it has something to do with the assigning of methods into the prototype property._

Comment: @JosephMCasey I think you need to study up on your terminology because almost nothing that you're saying is making sense. If a method is assigned to the prototype of a constructor function, then instances of that "class" will have access to those methods. It's as simple as that. Any function can be a "class" constructor.

Comment: @MikeC My terminology is definitely bad, but I think the code is pretty explicit in the desired outcome? It's a question on scoping a working piece of code into a class.

Comment: @JosephMCasey Did you look at my answer? Does that address your issue?

Comment: @MikeC well, it doesn't exactly. The goal was to wrap the code into a class, so I could avoid globally declaring variables.

Comment: @JosephMCasey You aren't declaring any global variables in my answer, other than `property`.

Comment: @MikeC Well, in the second section of the code, you did indeed scope the variable. =\ I guess I was just hoping to figure out a cleaner means of writing that out via a class wrapper with returnable functions.

Comment: @JosephMCasey: What are your issues with scoping? Are you talking about the first snippet? What is wrong with it - please show us how you use it so that you get unexpected results or errors?! Also, are you confusing scoping (lexical variable scope) with invocation contexts (`this` keyword)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem what you want to do is attach a constructor to a prototype so you can do something like this:

```
var thing = new Thing();
var otherThing = new thing.OtherThing();
```

If so, it's as simple as attaching a function to the prototype like you were before:

```
var property = function(){};
property.prototype.get = function() { ... };
property.prototype.set = function(value_) = { ... };

// Here's your extra constructor
property.prototype.id = function(id) {
    this.value = id;
};
property.prototype.id.prototype = Object.create(property.prototype);
property.prototype.id.constructor = property.prototype.id;
```

Or if you wanted it to be cleaner:

```
var id = function(id) {
    this.value = id;
};
id.prototype = Object.create(property.prototype);
id.constructor = id;

property.prototype.id = id;
```

Comment: yeah, that would work… except it does not make any sense.

Comment: @Bergi What about it doesn't make sense?

Comment: I just think it's an overkill to have a constructor in a prototype of another constructor. Haven't seen this much, mainly just constructors grouped in an object.

Comment: @MinusFour I agree but I can imagine reasons for doing this (say, some kind of database interface where you have models attached to whichever database wrapper object you're using). Not exactly common but not horrible either.

Comment: You'd have to instantiate one object just to reach the constructor you really want to instantiate. That design is just really unnecessary.

Comment: @MinusFour Unless you make the other constructor available elsewhere. Again, I agree that it's weird but it is valid.

Comment: @MikeC: It doesn't make sense to put a constructor as a property on an instance that does not relate to that particular instance. Creating the instance if you only want the constructor is useless. Rather put the "sub"constructor as a static property on the first constructor, or have it completely standalone.